# How could I show floating text?

Tags: macos, text, automation

What would be a simple way to show some text "floating in space" on osx.

The text should have a transparent background and I want to pick a color, a font, and some message (with newlines maybe) with the text appearing in front of all other windows.

I mainly want this so I can flexibly and quickly capture screenshots/screencasts with easy text overlays. (Not all tools have any text support, or if they do, it can be inflexible.)

Comment: Mac? iOS? Apple TV? could you elaborate on what hardware / software you want to control?

Comment: Sorry, added hardware/OS tags.